# why java post method connection timeout even it runs on browser?

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

I look network on developer tab(google chrome) and here is the ss

[image: my_image]

I want to get data on java app.

My code is here:

```
   String urlParameters  = "tabloNo=4&yil=2017&ay=2&paraBirimi=TL&taraf=10001";

        byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
        int postDataLength = postData.length;
        String request = "http://172.168.12*.15/getreport";
        URL url = new URL( request );
        HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "pplication/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
//        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding:", "gzip, deflate" );
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "tr,en;q=0.8" );
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength ));
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");  
        conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "ebulten.bddk.org.tr"  );
        conn.setRequestProperty("Origin","http://172.168.12*.15/");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Connection", "keep-alive" );
        conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://172.168.12*.15/" );
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36" );
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest" );
        conn.setUseCaches(true); 
        try(DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())) {
           wr.write( postData );
        }
```

it gives **Connection timed out: connect**

### note:

it is public website and everyone read data. I want to read it with programmatically.

thanks in advance

Comment: The guys you're trying to parse probably have some sort of protection against it. It could be quite sophisticated. They could track some cookies, check if specific javascript was executed etc. And they could also even add remote addresses to their black-list for failing those check too much

Comment: so I cant it with java ?

Comment: it has nothing to do with java. it just means that to fetch the data programmatically you need to understand what sort of protection they have. But at this point I __strongly advise__ you to check their "legal" section. There are high chances you're violating their terms with this and if you get caught - they will sue you. But the latest is my guess.